# Ext JS documention list of events with correct syntax

Tags: events, extjs

I am very new to the Ext Js Framework, i have little knowledge about MVC in Ext Js , Now i want to know the events specify in the Controller .where can i find the list of events with correct syntax. for example : click,dblclick,itemdblclick,etc

Comment: You should visit http://docs.sencha.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [the API Documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/), you can find events, config options, properties and more there.